# Email Regex for single character domain names

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that only works with two letter domains or more.  I need this to work with single letter domains as well.  Please suggest changes to the regex below.

```
^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$
```

Comment: You should really use a package/module to handle emails, they do a much more throughout job and are less error-prone.

I can't read that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will cover single letter domains.

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```